# install windows 7 through bootcamp on mac without cd

Tags: mac, boot-camp

I want to install windows 7 through bootcamp and i have mountain lion currently installed. When i go through bootcamp to make the partition it forces me to insert a windows 7 cd. But i have a iso of the operating system and my cd rom cd on the mini keeps spitting out cds and it only works when it chooses to. Is there any possibility that i can virtualize a cdrom like i did on windows like a daemon where i can mount the iso and make the os think i have inserted a cd?

Answer (score 2):

Okie, i have tried this:
[1] use boot camp to partition the drive easily.
[2] reboot the system with the USB drive attached (assuming u have windows 7 on a pen-drive and is bootable, and u can make it using an ISO, just google it)
[3] hold down Option / Alt key while booting, and install it on the windows partition u created.

Comment: in order to partition with bootcamp it requires a cd to be inserted. use daemon tools (http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/downloads) to make the computer think the iso file is a cd.

Comment: no it doesn't , it partitions it first, then it asks for the DVD for installation..